# Enforce metadata in MLFlow

Tags: python-3.x, mlflow

I am have deployed MLFlow in my direct team and have been using it for the past month with great success. One thing our team decided on was a set of metadata that we agreed was a requirement for any model that was pushed to the model registry. We are hoping to open MLFlow to the rest of our group but we see no way to enforce this metadata option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Create a plugin for overriding definitions of Model Registry APIs like `mlflow.register_model`: [plugins docs](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/plugins.html#writing-your-own-mlflow-plugins) [example registry plugin](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/branch-1.5/mlflow/store/model_registry/sqlalchemy_store.py#L34)
2. Create a helper function that everyone in your org agrees to use when registering models.

The helper functions could be of the following form:

```
import mlflow

def check_metadata_and_register(model_uri, name, await_registration_for=300, *, tags: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None):
    # any metadata checks you're enforcing
    status = ...

    # one or more checks failed
    if not status:
        return status

    # forward arguments to `register_model` when all checks succeed!
    return mlflow.register_model(model_uri=model_uri, name=name, ...)
```

Comment: Great find on the plugin side, I didn't even know that was an option. We will probably start with the helper function to start!